# Survey should not sent if last survey date is less than 7 days

Tags: workflow

I am implementing a workflow rule when last survey date is less than 7 days.

I am trying to implement null scenario here when last survey date is null survey should go.

```
NOW()-BLANKVALUE(Last_Survey_Date__c, Now())) > 7
```

But when last survey date is null also survey is going which is not expected. How do i handle null scenario here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is wrong here

You're assuming that the date is `NOW()` If a Survey Date is null, but `NOW() - NOW()` is never going to be `> 7`

Instead of `NOW()` for the `BLANKVALUE` choice, use a date sufficiently in the past, like '2000-1-1' or similar.

Comment: NOW()-BLANKVALUE(Contact.Last_Survey_Date__c, DATETIMEVALUE(1950,1,1)) > 7.   I am trying this but gives error.

Comment: That should do it

Comment: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'DATETIMEVALUE()'. Expected 1, received 3

Comment: use `DATEVALUE("2000-01-01")` instead

Comment: Or `DATETIMEVALUE( "2000-01-01 12:00:00" )`